# Links between two forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, web, webbrowser-control

Hi I'm currently working on a project where I want to be able to take the information from form1 in this case its address details for google maps then have google maps appear in a separate form to the previous. The main reason I want to keep them separate is because I have my database linked to the first one.

I have included a copy of my code in which I'm 90% finished but just need someone to show me simple line of code to link the web browser on Form 2 to Form 1

Private Sub BTNMap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNMap.Click
        Form2.Show()

```
    Dim Postcode As String = PostcodeTextBox.Text
    Dim Address As String = AddressTextBox.Text


    Try
        Dim queryAddress As New StringBuilder
        queryAddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=")

        If PostcodeTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            queryAddress.Append(Postcode + "," & "+")
        End If

        If AddressTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            queryAddress.Append(Address + "," & "+")
        End If


        Internet.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve data")
    End Try

End Sub
```

P.S

I have not put any could on form 2 as I don't no what to write to link the pair. Also a little explanation I wish to take the information on form to be presented on google maps form 2

The problem is   Internet.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString)

I'm very new to programming so be easy on me

Comment: use a class to hold and manage Important Data rather than forms.  The class can post the data to whatever form it needs to

Comment: Would it be possible to  get a small example

Comment: Would it be possible to get a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fully qualified name of the object in the other class you wish to access.
*Note - The object must have an access level of **Public**, to be accessible from outside the class in which it was declared.

Example:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
        Form2.WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```